# Filter on Elasticsearch terms query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am looking for the last time any user has logged in.

I have two authentication types ( Admin, Client) and am trying to do a query to find the event: Authentication succeeded Where authentication_type: Client

closest I have come is:

```
params='{ "query":{"terms":{"event_type":["authentication_succeeded"]}}}'
data=$(curl -XGET "localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?scroll=10m&size=500&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d"${params}")
```

After many variations and alternate query types but I have not been able to successfully append the filter for '{"authentication_type":"Client"}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `authentication_type` and `event_type` as keyword and then use the term filters on these fields in your search query.

You can read with an example filter with [multiple terms in this official ES link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context-ex).

**Below is a step by step example which uses your data to show the expected search results.**

### Index mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "authentication_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "event_type" :{
        "type" : "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Index sample docs

```
{
   "authentication_type" : "Client",
   "event_type" : "authentication_succeeded"
}

{
   "authentication_type" : "Client",
   "event_type" : "authentication_failed"
}

{
   "authentication_type" : "Admin",
   "event_type" : "authentication_succeeded"
}

{
   "authentication_type" : "Admin",
   "event_type" : "authentication_failed"
}
```

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "event_type": "authentication_succeeded"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "authentication_type": "Client"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Search Result

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so_60750542",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
               "authentication_type": "Client",
               "event_type": "authentication_succeeded"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: I had tried that page many times but missed the index mapping of authentication_type. Thank You